# Gradle sync field in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just tired to create my first android application and installed android studio 3.0.1 with API 27 , 26 and other necessary SDK tools but after creating a new project now I get a " Gradle sync field error " with no error number but with a 6 message error in "Message gradle sync" ... I didn't find a good solution for that .. may anyone help me ?

Note : I have jdk 1.8 on my windows and android studio uses from it and the embeded jdk is uncheck !

This is the screenshot of my problem !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you added `google()` maven repository?

Comment: excuse mi ... I'm new to java and I don't know what is google() maven repository! what's that ?

Comment: Follow this and check if you have done this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven Also, ensure that you are on Android Studio 3 or above.

Comment: Could you please show all the dependencies present in the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

As you removed the Expresso Dependency from Build.Gradle
you need to remove the Testclass also. Because method in that ApplicationTestClass needs that dependencies.

Try deleting your test class.

java->your_package(androidTest)->delete the files here**

Also add in your Build.Gradle(Project : ) //First one

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check build.gradle replace classpath with -
   classpath :'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha02'
2. check- compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

3.update all libraries build.gradle -compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'